# insert array of Int in prisma

Tags: arrays, insert, prisma

My `datamodel.prisma` looks like the following:

```
type Group {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  postcodes: [Int!]!
}
```

I have generated a prisma-client, and then calling `createGroup()` as follows:

```
await prisma.createGroup({ name: group.name, postcodes: [1, 2] });
```

I am getting an error

```
{ Error: Variable '$data' expected value of type 'GroupCreateInput!' but got: {"name":"Albury","postcodes":[1,2]}. Reason: 'postcodes' Expected 'GroupCreatepostcodesInput',
 found not an object. (line 1, column 11):
```

Any idea how to insert an array of `Int` in prisma?

Answer (score 2):

For an array, Prisma expect you to use `set`:

```
await prisma.createGroup({ name: group.name, postcodes: { set: [1, 2] } });
```